# When subtracting two raster with different cell sizes using raster math, what value is used for smaller cells?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, resampling

After reading the answer to a similar question ([What will happen if we subtract two raster with different cell size using Raster Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134119/what-will-happen-if-we-subtract-two-raster-with-different-cell-size-using-raster/134124#134124)), I am still left with a question. When the raster with smaller cells is resampled, how do the values in the smaller cells get aggregated into a larger cell? Does it take the mean of the smaller cells being combined? Is there a way to choose?

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018700000006000000